# If $G,H \subseteq X$ are closed sets, then $G \cup H$ is closed

Tags: sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space.

If $G,H \subseteq X$ are closed sets, then $G \cup H$ is closed.

Proof. Suppose $(a_n)$ is a convergent sequence in $G \cup H$. This means that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, a_n \in G \cup H \Rightarrow a_n \in G$ or $a_n \in H$. Let $(a_n) \to a$, where $a \in X$. To prove that $G \cup H$ is closed, it suffices to show that $a \in G \cup H$.

Assume for contradiction that $a \notin G \cup H$. Consider $a^{-1}(G)$ and $a^{-1}(H)$, so $a^{-1}(G) \cup a^{-1}(H)=\mathbb{N}$.

Right now my approach is to show that if we consider only the terms in $G$, we would have a subsequence of a convergent sequence $(a_n) \in G \cup H$. And if we have a subsequence of a convergent sequence, then it must converge to the same limit. But I'm not sure how to structure this argument mathematically.

Please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: The intersection of two open sets is (by definition) open. Can you see how that implies your statement?

Comment: @MartinR The definition of a closed set seems to differ from standard here: set $H$ is closed iff for any convergent sequence in $H$, its limit belongs to $H$.